# is it possible to deploy jar in tomcat which has scheduled job?

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to deploy a jar in tomcat? 
i have created a jar using maven. Now can i deploy it in tomcat? i have scheduled some job and packaged it.

Tomcat deploying a jar

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start JAR directly by using

```
java -jar /path/to/yourJar.jar
```

Tomcat is a web container, it deploys webapplication,  it reads `web.xml` and starts the web application as instructed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. to schedule the job should i create war instead of jar? Thanks!

Comment: You can simply run jar that runs forever and does the required scheduled task, or use native OS's scheduling feature